# Is there a way to get an absolute path of a file which is not in the current working directory (in Python)?

Tags: python, file, directory, path, absolute

I was wondering if there is any function/tool in Python which allows me to get the absolute path of a file directly from the computer, instead of having to manually search for the absolute path of the particular file, or having to shift the file to the same folder as the script. I am trying to access a .csv file stored in another folder different from my python script.

Comment: You can easily obtain the absolute path from a relative path. But you question is very unclear about what information you have about the location of the file.

Comment: Do you know the relative path to your csv from your script path? If not, then there is no other way than searching.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `os.path` module. See the `join` method which will accept relative path fragments and the `abspath` method which will give you the absolute path.